# why does an http post from a mobile device occasionally fail?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload, multipartform-data

i run a site that lets you record from your phone and post the audio to my apache2 server (it is an Amazon micro instance).  however, every once in awhile the post doesn't go through successfully, the php multipart request handler script has a file that's either a size of 0 or sometimes a size of 32.

why could this be? it happens 1 in every 20 or 30 uploads, and i'd like it to happen for 0.  any way I can prevent this?

Comment: If it's a size of 32, it would be very interesting to see what's in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how "consistent" the connection of a mobile device is, but if the user is running around with it through a city it will occasionally lose connection and (immediately) reconnect. It's obvious that will destroy the upload.

Answer (score 1):

look into setting up some logging on a lower level, like webserver level or maybe even tcp/ip. Like, get a packet sniffer program and have it log stuff.